# Appending "," to every item in a List of integers

Tags: python, python-3.x, append, iteration

I want to append "," and then the item index to every item in a list of integers.

I know that I need to convert the integers to strings before I do that, but even if I do that, it isn't working:

(I use Python 3.7.3)

```
for element in mylist:
    element = str(element)
    element = "{0},".format(element)
    element = element + mylist.index(element)
```

What I want:

```
mylist = ["97,0", "569,1", "39,2", "230,3",....]
```

Comment: You can't change the list values this way. You need to use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for this: `["{},{}".format(str(v), i) for i, v in enumerate(mylist)]`

Answer (score 1):

Possibly someone can link to a question of which this is a duplicate, but I don't know my way around that well yet.

You want [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), and the [enumerate function](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#enumerate).

```py
new_list = ["{0},{1}".format(item, index) for (index, item) in enumerate(old_list)]
```

Comment: You forget to put `enumerate` in list comprehension.

Comment: f-strings make this prettier since he's in 3.7. `new_list = [f"{item},{index}" for index, item in enumerate(old_list)]`

Comment: He's already got "".format() in the question, and working in PHP made me dislike that _code inside strings_ style.

Comment: Well you can bring a PHP programmer to water, but you can't make him drink ;). I kid -- I've spent exactly 8 professional hours in your language and I ran for the hills :D

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely positively need to change the list in-place, then you can iterate over a *copy* of that list and do just that.

```
for i, val in enumerate(mylist[:]):  # note the empty slice there -- that creates a whole copy!
    mylist[i] = f"{val},{i}"
```

Technically since you're not adding or removing elements, you are allowed to do this without that copy

```
for i, val in enumerate(mylist):
    mylist[i] = f"{val},{i}"
```

but this is a dangerous habit to get into without fully understanding what you can and cannot do to a list that you're iterating over. If your goal was to do this *but also* remove the 10th element (or etc), you would have to make a copy. Similarly if you wanted to insert a new element before the value `97`, or etc.

As general best practice, you should avoid mutating the list if possible and produce a new one using a list comprehension as recommended in [ShapeOfMatter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56101267/3058609)

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist = [97,0, 569,1, 39,2, 230,3]
for items in mylist:
    (str(items))
    print('\"{0}\"'.format(items))
```

Here is the solution to your question, if I understood it correctly you wanted to add for every item in the list "".